# обработка нескольких моделей Yii2 в одной форме

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Доброго.
Есть форма, на которой есть Пользователь, Компания и Множество Контактов компании.
Надо все заполнить разом (если компания есть, то привязать к уже существующей).
Вопрос такого плана, как лучше логически это построить? Валидация и прочее.

Допустим заполнили пользователя, если нажали галочку (или вписали название компании) то валидировать модель компании уже не надо. Если же нет, то валидируем компанию и валидируем множество моделей Контакт.

Мне бы схему работы всего этого, код я сам напишу. Просто я не совсем понимаю, как средствами юи сделать так, что бы красиво все было.

Comment: как понимаете так и строить, yii вас не ограничивает)

Answer (score 1):

В каждой модели необходимо описать реляцию (возможно в обе стороны) и с помощью метода `link()` сохранять связанные данные. Или стандартным способом - загрузили обе модели, проверили, сохранили.

**Примитивный вариант**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $user = User::findOne($id);
    $profile = Profile::findOne($id);

    if (!isset($user, $profile)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user was not found.");
    }

    $user->scenario = 'update';
    $profile->scenario = 'update';

    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $isValid = $user->validate();
        $isValid = $profile->validate() && $isValid;
        if ($isValid) {
            $user->save(false);
            $profile->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['user/view', 'id' => $id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'user' => $user,
        'profile' => $profile,
    ]);
}
```

**Вариант с использованием метода** `link()`

```
$customer = Customer::findOne(123);
$order = new Order();
$order->subtotal = 100;
// ...

$order->link('customer', $customer);
```

[Работа с несколькими моделями](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-input-multiple-models.html)

[Сохранение связных данных](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-active-record.html#saving-relations)