# Сохранить значение поля ActiveForm из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, yii2

Есть `ActiveForm`. Я вывожу значение из связанной таблицы:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'city_id')->textInput(['value' => $model->city->name]); ?>
```

Как это значение при сохранение модели теперь занести в связанную таблицу?

Этих значений из связанных таблиц может быть много, поэтому вариант ручной копии не сильно прильщает.

Answer (score 0):

Если в основной модели используется `city_id`, то название города скорее всего не строкой и не в инпут надо, а в выпадающий список.

Вот тут более подробно описал. Также есть ссылки на примеры с описанием. Нужен вариант с использованием `link()`

[обработка нескольких моделей Yii2 в одной форме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730967/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-yii2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5/731724#731724)