# Как определить Id добавленной записи в таблицу yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

есть две формы, которые добавляют данные в разные таблицы, в таблицу **address** нужно в поле **parent_id** вставить **id** добавленной записи таблицы **posts**, скрипт ниже записывает 0

//контроллер

```
public function actionIndex(){
        $model = new TestForm();
        $addrr = new AddressForm();
       if($addrr->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

           $isValid = $addrr->validate();
           $isValid = $model->validate();
           $addrr->parent_id = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID(); - эта строчка записывает 0

           if ($isValid) {
               $addrr->save(false);
               $model->save(false);
               return $this->refresh();
           }
        }
```

Comment: Я не работал с yii2, но в вашем коде я не вижу, где происходит запись в таблицу `posts`\

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov,  **$addrr->parent_id = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();** эту строку посредине надо было вставить, между $addrr и  $model

Comment: я бы рекомендовал использовать метод link() https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730967/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-yii2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5/731724#731724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $model = new TestForm();
    $addrr = new AddressForm();
   if($addrr->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

       $isValidAddr = $addrr->validate();
       $isValidModel = $model->validate();


       if ($isValidAddr && $isValidModel) {

           $model->save(false);
           $addrr->parent_id = $model->id;
           $addrr->save(false);
           return $this->refresh();
       }
    }
```