# Работа с несколькими моделями

Tags: php, yii2

Я новичок в YII2. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с редактированием данных пользователя взятых из нескольких моделей.
Я пишу админку для вымышленного проекта для закрепления навыков и изучения yii2. 
Так вот, у меня есть контроллер JobseekerControler в котором действие actionView, в файле вида View я вывожу данные пользователя по id, эти данные беруться из нескольких моделей примерно 6 моделей, как мне сделать возможность редактирования данных прямо на этой странице (View) для данных из всех использующихся моделей?

Comment: Вероятно поможет ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730967/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-yii2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5/731724#731724

Answer (score 0):

Пишешь смежную модель. В ней будут находится нужные тебе поля.
Потом,

```
$this->x = $mode1->someProp1;
$this->x1 = $mode2->someProp;
$this->x2 = $mode3->someProp;
$this->x3 = $mode4->someProp;
$this->x4 = $mode5->someProp;
```